# I need for my ASP.NET application to programmatically fill out a web form on another website for my users and then display it to them

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Essentially, I need for my ASP.NET application to programmatically fill out a web form on another website for my users and then display that website to them.  There are no other requirements, so I am open to any suggestions for making this happen.

Is this even possible?

It can be using ASP.NET MVC or WebForms.

Comment: You mean "spoofing"?

Comment: I know this sounds nefarious, but I just want to save my users time by automatically filling out a very long web form for them.  The data is already available within the application, so I would just be place it in the form inputs for them.

Comment: Not sure what kind of suggestions you're looking for. Just write the code. If you get stuck, that'd be a more appropriate question to ask, making sure to include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

No, this is technically not possible. Form fields values may only be set either explicitly in the HTML or via JavaScript. Filling out a third-party form would not allow modifications to HTML (which is generated by the third-party) and any JavaScript solution would require that third-party running your JavaScript, which you obviously cannot force them to do.

You could perhaps embed the site in a frame within your site, which would then allow you to run JS on your site that could manipulate the site in the frame. However, this would require that the third-party allows their site to be framed in the first place and that they do not employ a Content Security Policy that would prevent your JS from running against their site. What you would be doing is basically an exploit, and if they have any reasonable security in place, it won't work because of that.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I've attempted embedding the site in a frame, within my site, but 1) content in iframes is not accessible via local JavaScript and 2) modern browsers block you from loading an external website inside of a div, etc.  You wouldn't happen to know a third way to accomplish this would you?

Comment: Yeah, I think you're bumping into same-origin with the iframe method. That's it, really. There's no other options, unless you can work with the third party to create a combined solution on your end and theirs.